# How should one request permissions from a custom Preference?

Tags: android, android-permissions, android-preferences, preferencefragment

I have a class that extends from `DialogPreference` which allows the user to choose from their calendars. As of Android M, the user must grant permission at runtime for the app to access the calendars. In an `Activity` or a `Fragment`, this would normally be relatively straightforward: a call to `ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(Activity [...])` or `FragmentCompat.requestPermissions(Fragment [...])` would do the trick.

However, in a `DialogPreference`, there is no obvious way of accessing the `Activity` or `Fragment` that uses the `DialogPreference`. `getContext()` cannot be guaranteed to refer to an Activity, so casting that to an `Activity` may be unreliable. Using `instanceOf` smacks of ugliness, and does not solve the issue where `getContext()` does not refer to an `Activity`.

`getDialog().getOwnerActivity()` looks promising, but returns null when it is needed (e.g. during the `DialogPreference`'s `onBindView()` method).

What is the best practice for requesting permissions needed by a `Preference`? Should the request for permissions be removed completely from the `Preference` and placed in the `PreferenceFragment`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Should the request for permissions be removed completely from the Preference and placed in the PreferenceFragment?

IMHO, yes. Or, more accurately: request the permissions before showing the preferences.

Answer (score 0):

My project `TestPreferenceFragment extends PreferenceFragment{...}`.

Don't callback `onRequestPermissionsResult` When I use the operates:

- `getActivity().requestPermissions(……)`
- `ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(getActivity(),……)`

Then I fix it by:`PreferenceFragment.requestPermissions()`

Answer (score 0):

In fragment, ask permission just using

```
requestPermissions(permissionList, REQUEST_CODE)
```

instead of

```
ActivityCompat.requestPermission(Activity, String[], int)
```